# Making context manager class a decorator

Tags: python, class, decorator, contextmanager

I have a class that I use for db connections as context manager:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self._conn = psycopg2.connect(host=os.environ['DB_SERVER'],
                            database=os.environ['DB_NAME'],
                            user=os.environ['DB_USER'],
                            password=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD'])
        self._cursor = self._conn.cursor()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.close()

    @property
    def connection(self):
        return self._conn

    @property
    def cursor(self):
        return self._cursor

    def commit(self):
        self.connection.commit()

    def close(self, commit=True):
        if commit:
            self.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, params or ())

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def query(self, sql, params=None):
        self.cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
        return self.fetchall()
```

And I want to use it as decorator. I wrote decorator as function *with_connection* and it works fine.

```
def with_connection(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with Database() as db:
            return func(db, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

I use it with other functions like this:

```
@with_connection
def selectfunc(conn, *args, **kwargs):
...
```

Now I want to implement *call* magic method in Database class and use class as a decorator instead of using separate function, I guess I need something like this:

```
def __call__(self, f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwds):
        with self as db:
            return f(db, *args, **kwds)
    return decorated
```

First I got TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. So I added *args and **kwargs to init method but then I got TypeError: **call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'.

I would appreciate some help on how to implement call method correctly and use this class as a decorator.

Comment: Why do you want to do it through `__call__` ?
The _call_ ability will be available on a instance of your class. A decorator is actually a function, how would the decorator know which Database instance to use?

Comment: Could you show how you use it?

Comment: @FlorinC. Using `__call__` for decoration is a common way to do it (see for example [here](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/p/decorators-and-monkey-patching.html))

Comment: @Timus, your answer does not state why, only that is common, which I doubt it. I can understand that it can be done (the linked examples seem to provide the full mechanics) but it seems complicated and quite easy to get it wrong. I am curious how can this "pattern" be helpful.

Comment: @FlorinC. Indeed, _my_ comment didn't address your question directly. But Graham gives detailed reasons for why he thinks his aproach is better (his blog is also referenced in the decorator chapter of _Fluent Python_). I like his aproach and use it a lot, so I'm probably biased.

Comment: Alright, the topic can cause a long discussion (but also interesting). So, to give @DenisK a hand, your question is answered in detail in the blog mentioned by Timus, have a look at http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/01/maintaining-decorator-state-using-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Your class is correct, and implementing `__call__` to turn a class into a decorator is normal. For completeness here you have the `Database` class. I have added a connect method to separate initialization and actual connection to the database, this makes sure that it happens closer to when your functions use the database.

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.connect()
        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.close()
        
    def connect(self):
        print("Connecting")
        
    def close(self):
        print("Closing connection")
    
    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self as db:
                return func(db, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```

The exception that you get is because you are using it like this:

```
@Database
def echo(conn, x):
    return x
```

Instead of like this:

```
@Database()
def echo(conn, x):
    return x
```

You need to pass an instance, not the class itself. In the first example `__init__` gets called, Python tries to pass both self and the decorated function to it, which is one too many arguments.

If you liked the old function name you can also do something like this:

```
with_connection = Database()

@with_connection
def echo(conn, x):
    return x
```

If you follow this approach definitely split initialization and connection, otherwise you are going to have problems.